# How do I get indentation of bullet list (python-docx)

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-docx

I don't know what am I doing wrong. Based on the ruler in Word `left_indent` is the place where the text begins. So, I tried `left_indent` and it doesn't work, it only works on the normal text, with no bullet. Then I tried `first_line_indent`, doesn't work either.

Btw, here's my code:

```
import docx

def getText(filename):
    doc = docx.Document(filename)
    fullText = []
    for paragraph in doc.paragraphs:
        indent = ''
        if paragraph.paragraph_format.left_indent:
            indent = ' ' * int(round(paragraph.paragraph_format.left_indent / 100000))
        fullText.append(indent + paragraph.text)
    return '\n'.join(fullText)

print(getText(r"file.docx"))
```

I'm trying to extract Word to string as simple as possible, don't mind my nasty code.

ref: https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/styles-using.html